# Module config in Zend Framework 1.10

Tags: php, zend-framework, module

I am using reccomended app. structure ( http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/project-structure.filesystem.html ) in Zend Framework but I cant get each module config working.
It just doesn't load modules/mymodule/configs/application.ini file into configuration.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty hard to answer with no code examples, so all I can offer for help is this article by Matthew Weier O'Phinney:

- [Module Bootstraps in Zend Framework: Do's and Don'ts](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/234-Module-Bootstraps-in-Zend-Framework-Dos-and-Donts.html)

It might shed some light onto some of your module problems.

Answer (score 0):

Check the solutions offered by Pádraic Brady, one of the active contributors to the Zend Framework project.

Here is [zfproposals - sample project on github](http://github.com/padraic/zfproposals).